# One large file, or several small files?

Tags: c++, filesystems, stdio

I'm writing 3D model data out to file, while includes a lot of different types of information (meshes, textures, animation, etc) and would be about 50 to 100 mb in size.

I want to put all this in a single file, but I'm afraid it will cost me if I need to read only a small portion of that file to get what I want.

Should I be using multiple smaller files for this, or is a single very large file okay?  I don't know how the filesystem treats trying to jump around giant files, so for all I know iterating through a large file may either be costly, or no problem at all.

Also, is there anything special I must do if using a single large file?

Comment: `I don't know how the filesystem treats trying to jump around giant files, so for all I know iterating through a large file may either be costly, or no problem at all. ` Jumping around isn´t the same as reading everything fro the beginning until some specific location. Jumping is ok.

Comment: What counts as "very large" in this context?

Comment: @MatsPetersson - about 50mb.  It's not... massive I guess, but it's the largest file size I use regularly

Comment: FWIW Quake does this using *zip* files. Although it uses multiple *zip* files and some kind of virtual fs to resolve paths. For each map it just loads what it wants from the *zips*. I suppose using *zip* files solves the indexing problem to locate the specific data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no issue with accessing data in the middle of a file - the operating system won't need to read the entire file, it can skip to any point easily. Where the complexity comes in is you'll need to provide an index that can be read to identify where the various pieces of data are.

For example, if you want to read a particular animation, you'll need a way to tell your program where this data is in the file. One way would be to store an index structure at the beginning of the file, which your program would read to find out where all of the pieces of data are. It could then look up the animation in this index, discover that it's at position 24680 and is 2048 bytes long, and it could then seek to this position to read the data.

You might want to look up the `fseek` call if you're not familiar with seeking within a file: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/